# Google App Engine and 404 error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404

I've setup a static website on GAE using hints found elsewhere, but can't figure out how to return a 404 error. My app.yaml file looks like

```
- url: (.*)/
  static_files: static\1/index.html
  upload: static/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: static
```

with all the static html/jpg files stored under the static directory. The above works for files that exist, but returns a null length file if they don't. The answer is probably to write a python script to return a 404 error, but how do you set things up to serve the static files that exist but run the script for files that don't?

Here is the log from fetching a non-existent file (nosuch.html) on the development application server:

```
ERROR    2008-11-25 20:08:34,084 dev_appserver.py] Error encountered reading file "/usr/home/ctuffli/www/tufflinet/static/nosuch.html":
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/home/ctuffli/www/tufflinet/static/nosuch.html'
INFO     2008-11-25 20:08:34,088 dev_appserver.py] "GET /nosuch.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: I would label this 'python' but I don't have access (yet)...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to register a catch-all script handler. Append this at the end of your app.yaml:

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

In main.py you will need to put this code:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class NotFoundPageHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.error(404)
        self.response.out.write('<Your 404 error html page>')

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', NotFoundPageHandler)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Replace `<Your 404 error html page>` with something meaningful. Or better use a template, you can read how to do that [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/gettingstarted/templates.html).

Please let me know if you have problems setting this up.

Comment: It looks like the last line in my original app.yaml matches before the one you suggest adding

Comment: This works, but I prefer Zachary's suggestion to use a static handler for the 404 page (see his answer below).

Comment: I'm trying to do it this way but if I set the 404 error, the html is not displayed whether I use a template or not.

Comment: does not work for cases when u've different urls like domain.com/admin/.* , domain.com/.* etc

Comment: To handle that (custom 404 for each section) case, you add a `('/admin/.*', NotFoundPageHandler')` in you app setup for each handler in app.yaml.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for a static_dir clause. It seems that any missing file in a static_dir returns its own (empty) 404 page instead of dropping through to other handlers.

Comment: Do handlers in the list take ordered priority? Or matched by specificity? i.e. if you had `[('/.*', NFPH), ('/.login', LoginH)]`, would `LoginH` ever get hit?

Answer (score 28):

google app engine now has [Custom Error Responses](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?csw=1#Python_app_yaml_Custom_error_responses)

so you can now add an error_handlers section to your app.yaml, as in this example:

```
error_handlers:

- file: default_error.html

- error_code: over_quota
    file: over_quota.html
```

Comment: where does the HTML file need to be located here?

Comment: you can put the HTML anywhere e.g. error_handlers:
- file: youappname/templates/default_error.html

Comment: Note: answer therefore does not answer question

Answer (score 4):

A significantly simpler way to do this without requiring any CPU cycles is to place this handler at the bottom of your app.yaml

```
- url: /.*
    static_files: views/404.html
    upload: views/404.html
```

This then allows you to place a static 404.html file in your views directory. No need for a python handler. Anything that isn't handled in your app.yaml already will hit that.

Comment: There isn't any way to return a 404 HTTP response code this way, is there?

Comment: Yah, all you have to do is add the header to your HTML file.

Comment: Maybe it is brilliant.. but it does not work in case of when u have nadlers/controllers for i.e. domain.com/admin/ and different for domain.com/ and u want to handle domain.com/admin/notexistent and also domain.com/nonexistent 404 error

Comment: This is wrong. You can't make static content return a status code other than 200.

Comment: This also does not catch `/views/nonexistentpage.htm` when there is a previous directive `- url: /views \\ static_dir: html`

Comment: To add to @NickJohnson - it's not a limitation, it's a definition: if you're serving static content, it *was* found!

Comment: well, a simple directive could be put in place for this use case. See how today hosting a static website in Google Cloud Storage handles this. They have both a setting for "index" pages and "404" pages. I don't know why this is not implemented in app engine static_dir handler

Answer (score 4):

You can create a function to handle your errors for any of the status codes. You're case being 404, define a function like this:

```
def Handle404(request, response, exception):
     response.out.write("Your error message") 
     response.set_status(404)`
```

You can pass anything - HTML / plain-text / templates in the `response.out.write` function. Now, add the following declaration after your `app` declaration.

`app.error_handlers[404] = Handle404`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

`webapp2` provides the `error_handlers` dictionary that you can use to serve custom error pages.
Example below:

```
def handle_404(request, response, exception):
    logging.warn(str(exception))
    response.set_status(404)
    h = YourAppBaseHandler(request, response)
    h.render_template('notfound')

def handle_500(request, response, exception):
    logging.error(str(exception))
    response.set_status(500)
    h = YourAppBaseHandler(request, response)
    h.render_template('servererror')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route('/', MainHandler, name='home')
    ], debug=True)
app.error_handlers[404] = handle_404
app.error_handlers[500] = handle_500
```

More details are available on `webapp2`'s documentation pages: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/app.html#error-handlers

Comment: This was very helpful due to the nature of existing webapp2 routes (pages and wildcards) which caused other solutions to not work properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The dev_appserver is already returning 404 responses for anything that doesn't match the mapping, or does match the mapping but doesn't exist. The 404 response itself has no body, but it's still a 404:

```
$ wget -O - http://127.0.0.1:8080/foo
--2010-10-28 10:54:51--  http://127.0.0.1:8080/foo
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 
2010-10-28 10:54:51 ERROR 404: (no description).

$ wget -O - http://127.0.0.1:8080/foo/
--2010-10-28 10:54:54--  http://127.0.0.1:8080/foo/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 
2010-10-28 10:54:54 ERROR 404: (no description).
```

If you want to return a more user-friendly error page, follow jonmiddleton's advice and specify a custom 404 page.

Comment: It does not work that way I think error_code can be ^(default|over_quota|dos_api_denial|timeout)$ and default one does NOT handle 404 error

Comment: @rafek Then specify a catchall handler, as Alexander suggests. Either way, the correct response code is already being returned by the default handlers, just without an explanatory message for users.

Comment: @Nick: if I have /admin/.* handler and (all) /.* handler and do what Alexander suggests.. then the case with domain.com/admin/stuff-that-doesnt-exist is not handled.. coz /admin/.* handler in app.yaml handles it.. and then I should have catch all handler for every script - that's awfull code duplication.

Comment: Then limit your handlers to one, or have a module that contains a 404 handler that you import in each handler, and set as the catchall.

Comment: One handler _script_ - as many handlers as you want. Most people use one per 'app'.

Answer (score 2):

I have reviewed all the above given answers and used the following at the end as the most universal 404 solution:

Add this link at the end of `app.yaml`

```
- url: /(.*) 
  script: 404.app
```

and create `404.py` with the following content

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class NotFound(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.error(404)
    self.response.out.write(template.render('404.html', {}))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/.*', NotFound)
], debug=True)
```

This will display contents of `404.html` file with 404 error code.

The advantage of this solution is simplicity, correctness of bahaviour and flexibility, as it allows to use a static `404.html` file as error page content.

I also want to warn against some of the solutions suggested above.

- `Custom Error Responses` don not work with 404 error
- Also don't use static files, as they would return 200 instead of 404 error. This can cause a lot of headache ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on jonmiddleton's answer, but the custom error responses is for App engine specific errors by the look of it.
I don't see a way to specify a custom 404 page.

Django let's you [specify](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#handler404) one though.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to handle both 404 and permanent redirects in a catch all handler that I put as the last one. This is usefull when I redesign and app and rename/substitute urls:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ...
    ...
    ('/.*', ErrorsHandler)
], debug=True)


class ErrorsHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        p = self.request.path_qs
        if p in ['/index.html', 'resources-that-I-removed']:  
            return self.redirect('/and-substituted-with-this', permanent=True)
        else: 
            self.error(404)
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('404.html')
            context =  {
                'page_title': '404',
            }
            self.response.out.write(template.render(context))
```