# Google App Engine: 403 and 404 error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How do I implement using python if I want to manage the 403 and 404 error, for example, to know which URL is most the 403 or 404 error?

Comment: possible dupe:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189751/google-app-engine-and-404-error

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do this manually on App Engine. Just take a look at the "Errors" section in the dashboard for your app.

For more information on this, see http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/kb/general.html#erroruris