# How to set custom NotFound page in Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I hosted my static web pages on Google App Engine (Java). It does not have any server side coding.

I used HTML5 Boilerplate code as my base. It has page called 404.html. I would like to show this `404.html` page when there is page not found error.

How can I show a custom 404 page in Google App engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you can set up [error handlers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Error_Handlers) in your `web.xml` file (which is located in the app's WAR under the WEB-INF/ directory).

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/errors/servererror.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set [custom error responses](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Custom_Error_Responses) in your `app.yaml` file.

Comment: Thanks. I use Java(not python). Is it web.xml for java? Can you give sample file to configure 404 page?

Comment: You can not have a default error handler for custom HTTP error states, for example 404: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774451/error-handlers-on-app-yaml

Comment: If your app produces 404, then is it's responsibility to show error page instead.

Comment: Thanks. I found it
`<error-page>
     <error-code>404</error-code>
     <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/errors/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>`