# Is there a way of getting 404 error page set up on the app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, http-status-code-404

I have set up a website and I want to set up a 404 error page. Is there a way of doing this as i can't seem to access the .htaccess file?

Thanks in advance,
Scott

Comment: If your looking for a .htaccess file on appengine then you really need to do some reading on the basics of app engine.  You will save yourself a lot of time getting your head around the architecture, rather than looking for apache equivalents etc..

Answer (score 0):

python? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Custom_Error_Responses

java?
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Custom_Error_Responses

see [Google App Engine and 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189751/google-app-engine-and-404-error)

Comment: Custom error handlers are generic and therefore won't be specific to a 404 error page.

Comment: what about this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10861989/1258245 makes me think if you could forward to a servlet instead of an html page, that you could do the same in java

Comment: if you read through that thread, pay attention to Nick Johnsons responses.  static handlers can't return anything but 200 response.
You normally have a 404 handler,

Answer (score 0):

The documentation now clearly states that custom 404 pages will not work.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/webxml#Error_Handlers

> Note: At present, you cannot configure custom error handlers for some error conditions. Specifically, you cannot customize the 404 response page when no servlet mapping is defined for a URL, the 403 quota error page, or the 500 server error page that appears after an App Engine internal error.