# Google App Engine WebApp/Python Custom 404 Handler Implementation

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

I'm using GAE, Google App Engine with Webapp using Python.

I've been trying to implement a custom error handler, or template, or along those lines. GAE provides some documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Custom_Error_Responses) however it doesn't provide enough in the example for implementation (for me).

I've also looked at all these wonderful examples on another StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189751/google-app-engine-and-404-error) - but cannot understand how to implement it into my current **main.py** file.

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
 def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'static/index.html'

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=False)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

I've tried making another class, and implementing it before the `MainHandler` as well as a new `def` in the `MainHandler`. The only times I've gotten the 404 to display, it's displayed globally, meaning even the `index.html` file  was a "404".

The last thing I tried was implementing something along the lines of:

```
if not os.path.exists (_file_):
 self.redirect(/static/error/404.html)
```

My **app.yaml** file is:

```
application: appname
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

error_handlers:
  - file: static/error/404.html

  - error_code: over_quota
    file: static/error/404.html

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt 

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon.ico    

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

I cannot find any guides/tutorials to the implementation of the 404 handler, just code extracts.

Much appreciated everyone!

Edit:
As per clarification from Hans below, **I want to return a 404 when a file (or directory) is not present in the filesystem.**

I've tried:

```
class ErrorHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
     if not os.path.isfile(_file_):
        self.redirect('/static/error/404.html')
```

to no avail. What's the correct implementation/syntax?

Edit:
To Voscausa

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
import logging

import webapp2

def handle_404(request, response, exception):
    logging.exception(exception)
    response.write('Oops! I could swear this page was here!')
    response.set_status(404)

def handle_500(request, response, exception):
    logging.exception(exception)
    response.write('A server error occurred!')
    response.set_status(500)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route('/', handler='handlers.HomeHandler', name='home')
])
app.error_handlers[404] = handle_404
app.error_handlers[500] = handle_500

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'static/index.html'

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1: Have appengine take care of your static files**

You can have GAE handle your static files for you, like this:

```
application: appname
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

This is better as serving static files is much easier when it is done for you, and it will also not count as much towards your CPU quota.

There is just one warning. You cannot specify a custom error handled in case a file is not found below `/static`. As soon as a handler picks up on a url, it will try to finish the request. If the static dir handler cannot find the url, it will not hand control back to `main.py`, which is now your wildcard solution. It will simply return the default 404 error page from appengine.

**SOLUTION 2: Serve static files from your application**

If you **really** must create a **custom** 404 page for your static you have to do it in your application. (I do not advice you to do so, in case that's not clear.) In that case you were on the right track. You should create an extra handler like in your example. Just rewrite one line:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static', q)
```

In you application line, add your handler like this:

```
('/static/(.*)?', MainHandler),
```

If the file is not found, you should call self.response.set_status(404) and write whatever custom response message you need.

Comment: Not quite sure how to go about this, I've tried the former where I want a 404 displayed if the file or directory being accessed doesn't exist in my GAE-Project. I've tried an ErrorHandler with os.path.exists as well as os.pathisfile previously and again now, check original question for an edit towards you.

Comment: Just to clarify, why won't you let the GAE system handle static files for you? Is that because you want to specify a custom error page?

Comment: Also, I see that in your handler you lookup files from the same directory as your application is located in. It is ususally better to place your files in a different subdirectory.

Comment: Is it better for GAE to handle static files? I'm uploading all static .html files to folder /static/ with sub directories as I see fit for management of page content. I'm not even quite sure of GAE's default handling for static content, all I know was to set it up in the particular way I currently have which "works".

Comment: Would it just be possible to append the current dirname before the file name and do an exists/isfile check? Why would the .py/.yaml files need to be changed to another subdir?

Comment: Usually it is better to have GAE handle static files. It will not tax your CPU quota and stuff. I will adapt my answer to show how.

Comment: Cheers, but it would be nice for A) a custom error page or B) a redirect back to the main page. If B, I suppose it's possible to let GAE handle the static content for me. However, I still haven't been able to find a way of catching the error and initiating the redirect or 404 page.

Comment: This is not possible if you use `static_dir`. However, if you follow my second suggestion, you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/exceptions.html for handling 404 and 500 exceptions.
Webapp2 is now the preferred framework for GAE python applications.

Comment: I don't quite understand: "(request, response, exception)" need to be filled, correct? This is an incomplete example. Furthermore, "response.set_status(404)" you're setting the error rather than catching the error and displaying the error page based on it?

Comment: NO, the error is first catched by the handler, a custom message is displayed and the response header is set. So the client will receive a 404 (response header) with a custom message.

Comment: Copying and using it, it still creates a problem. All my pages are globally 404'ing, even though they are uploaded and are being accessed from the correct URL. Could you provide an appropriate example in your answer as to how to implement it within the **main.py** file I displayed in my question as to learn from it? Thanks.

Comment: What is in your app.yaml? These lines schould be the last lines in your app yaml: 
    - url: /.*
      script: main.py

Comment: Those are indeed the last lines in my file, as per the original question code that I've already outlined.

Comment: but there is a slash missing before .*