# How to add custom error page for 404 error (page not found)

Tags: google-app-engine, go, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages, vs-web-site-project

I am trying to add a custom 404 error page in my website for "Page Not Found" or putting wrong URL. I have **app.yaml** file and used Go language. My website is basically in Google App Engine. I have checked each and every example which I think its related to my problem in stack overflow. But in some example they explained example by Python or Java language but I want to find in Go language. because my code is written in Go.

The static error 404 page is loaded in server but when I filled wrong URL then it show error page not found instead my custom page. I have attached screenshot which tells you everything.

current:-
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ayje.jpg "This is what current showing"

Required:-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrapU.jpg  "This is what i want"

I have read google app engine's app.yaml documents and tried to put error-handlers but i did not find any solution.

**app.yaml file Code**

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:

-url: /

  static_files: www/index.html

  upload: www/index.html

-url: /(.*)

  static_files: www/\1

  upload: www/(.*)

error_handlers: 

  -file: www/page-not-found.html*
```

**Here's the updated app.yaml file:**

```
runtime: go

api_version: go1

error_handlers: 
  - file: /page-not-found.html

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html
- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of the `app.yaml` configuration file for Go apps can be found at [app.yaml Configuration File](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go112/config/appref).

Search for `error_handlers` on that page to see how it should be defined. It has the following red warning:

> Warning: Make sure that the path to the error response file does not overlap with static file handler paths.

You specified:

```
-file: www/page-not-found.html*
```

This overlaps with one of your static handler paths:

```
-url: /(.*)
 static_files: www/\1
 upload: www/(.*)
```

That's why your custom error page doesn't get served. You must place your error handler outside of the `www` folder (or not use the whole `www` folder as a static handler path, what matters is they can't overlap).

**Note:** I linked to the Go 1.12 app configuration, because Go 1.9 which you're using is depcerated and soon will become unavailable. Nonetheless, the same applies to both versions regarding custom error pages.

Comment: @SaurabhTripathi Please post your "improved" version.

Comment: icza .this is the improved version.. i've removed the page-not-found.html from www folder. and edit tag from app.yaml file. but still not find solution.                                                               runtime: go                                                                                                                                       
api_version: go1

error_handlers: 
  - file: /page-not-found.html

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html
- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)

Comment: @SaurabhTripathi Please edit your question, and "append" your new `app.yaml` with other details. It's hard to read it from the comments.

Comment: @SaurabhTripathi And where is your `page-not-found.html` file? Are you sure it is uploaded to AppEngine?

Comment: @icza are you certain `error_handlers` can be used for 404 responses? That is, does gae execute `error_handlers` when it encounters 404? I've seen comments indicating that that's not possible and answers usually suggesting the implementation of custom 404s in code rather than configuration... although I've seen repos on github that point to 404 templates in their `error_handlers` config, whether it works the way the developers expect is another thing... then there are repos like this ...

Comment: ...  https://github.com/AaronCRobinson/python_glass_canteen/blob/a7ecfcfc6b48d9f850bddcf754ed4116939dfb5e/app.yaml#L39-L41 and this answer got a comment that a lot of people seem to agree with https://stackoverflow.com/a/3722135/965900 (although it's old so i don't know how reliable it is)

Comment: when i put this page-not-found.html file outside of www folder then it is not showing showing to putting www.accem.com/page-not-found.html...otherwise if i insert this www folder it will overlaped but showing after direct link of this pge.

Comment: @icza these are the files in folder. in present time.. C:\Users\Accemy Admin\accemy.com https://imgur.com/a/sPAybo3  after this it opens www folder : https://imgur.com/a/B80GV66  please check and let me know the right way.

Comment: @mkopriva so what do u want to say, in GAE, There is nothing that will give me a custom error page service.

Comment: @SaurabhTripathi what I *want* to say is irrelevant. However what I *am* saying is, that it *seems* to me that custom handling of 404 errors is not possible in the app.yaml config with the `error_handlers` option. But it is possible in code and should therefore be implemented by your Go app instead of your config.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks, but if it is possible in code as u said. So will you please give me any help to implement this in Go app?

Comment: @mkopriva No, I haven't tried this if it can be used to override 404 responses...

Comment: @SaurabhTripathi I can't help you without seeing how you've setup your Go server code, for example if you're using a 3rd party router, like so many people do, the correct implementation will depend on that router. Also there's already a lot of questions and answers to how to handle custom 404 errors in Go, so I would suggest you first take a look at the existing answers and if none of them work for you, you either open a new question or update your old one with an example of your Go server code. Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgo%5D+custom+404+handler