# GAE how to serve 404 pages

Tags: google-app-engine

I have app engine an app with some static pages.

I want to serve my static content, and a script. Finally, I want to serve 404 for everything else.

My app.yaml file looks something like

```yaml
runtime: go113

handlers:
- url: /myscripy
  script: auto

- url: /$
  static_files: public/index.html
  secure: always
  upload: public/index.html

- url: /(.*/)?$
  static_files: public/\1index.html
  secure: always
  upload: public/(.*/)?index.html
  http_headers:
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

OK, that's working except a few things

1. it's unclear to me why the `- url: /$` is necessary, why is it not subsumed by `- url: /(.*/)?$`, but that's just a side note.
2. main problem: any URL that matches nothing will be rendered as empty file with a 200 status code instead of a 404.
3. I can force 404s by adding something like

```yaml
- url: /.*
  static_files: public/some_non_existing_file.html
  secure: always
  upload: public/some_non_existing_file.html
```

at the end of the app.yaml file, but that triggers an ugly 404 last ditch page that is not very appealing.

4. I can serve nice 404 custom pages like

```yaml
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  static_files: public/404.html
  upload: public/404.html
  http_headers:
    Status: 404
```

where public/404.html exists, however the Status: 200 header is sent before the Status: 404 header, making the whole response a 200.

5. I had hopes for

```yaml
error_handlers:
  - file: 404.html
```

to do something for me, but no, it seems to not do anything at all.

6. I can of course add a custom script to create the 404 response, but it feels a bit silly to me. Isn't there a better way ?

I'm a bit stumped - I can't believe that a long standing industry tool like GAE has no way to statically define a custom 404 page, or even render 404 status code for nonexisting pages.

Really appreciate any advice, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is not easier way for you to achieve the custom `404` page, then adding a custom script to create the `404` response. App Engine, unfortunately, still doesn't work very well with handling some errors, which includes the error `404`. As you can check in this official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/webxml#error-handlers), there is no custom handlers from this error on Java.

This is just an example that a custom script is the viable solution.Otherwise, the solutions won't return the error `404` - as you well mentioned - or you would need to use a catch-all handler, which is not very recommended as well, since it's too broad of a solution.

In case you are using Python, there is a very good example of how to configure the trigger and example of script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189751/google-app-engine-and-404-error).

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanks, Gabriel. I thought so, too, but I still can't believe the default is to serve nonexisting pages as empty 200-status pages. That's so ... harebrained, for lack of a better word. I'll hold off marking the question as definitely answered -- I still hope someone from the GAE team can give a really good explanation.

Comment: BTW - why I find this harebrained: there are many articles on the web suggesting to use GAE to host static websites. Not having valid 404s for non-existing pages seems to be a non-starter for anything that should be picked up by webcrawlers. Why does noone else point this out ?

Comment: Sure, I understand your point @KlapauciusKlapaucius , maybe it's worht it to open a feature request in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), so they can check about the possibility of implementing this in the future.